# Fabric js image quality is not getting good after set image height and width dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I have added image into canvas and dynamically I want to change image height and width according to the rectangle height and width. I have done calculation of image height and width according to rectangle height and width and original image height and width.

Using below code I have changed image height and width but image quality is getting very low

```
var image_height = 200; //For now here image height is dummy
var image_width = 150; //For now here image width is dummy
var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
obj.setHeight(image_height);
obj.setWidth(image_width);
obj.setCoords();
canvas.renderAll();
```

Comment: Sir, Height & width is not Good for photo. You must use any one between height or width for photo looks good. Thats Ok !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem a few days ago. The solution I found is to not try to set `width`and `height` but rather ask your image to *scale* up to the canvas dimensions.

Here is how I did it :

```
var scaleWidth = canvas.getWidth() / img.width;
var scaleHeight = canvas.getHeight() / img.height;
var scale = Math.min(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
bgImage = new fabric.Image(img, {
    [...]
    scaleX: scale,
    scaleY: scale,
    [...]
  });
canvas.add(bgImage);
canvas.sendToBack(bgImage); // useful in case you want a background but not **needed**
canvas.renderAll();
```

In the code above I compute width and height ratios, pick the lower one, and then I apply it on the picture using `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties.

If it still doesn't work for you, please let me know in the comments.

**EDIT :** I completed my linked code for more clarity.

**2nd EDIT :** It appears a method called `scale`exists and could be used on your image. Looks cleaner if you want to keep your ratio (aka `scaleX`and `scaleY` properties would have the same value).

Comment: Using above code it will update size of existing added image of canvas or should I right code for add image again?

Comment: In my case I set it before adding the image to the canvas, but I believe you should be able to update an existing (already added) image by setting `scaleX` and `scaleY`, using `setOptions` method.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your solution and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

When you export canvas to image, You can add multiplier. It will increase resolution as well as size of image.

```
canvas.toDataURL({ multiplier: 8 });
```